# AnimationDrawable programmatically without animation-list xml

Tags: android, android-animation

I am in a situation where I want to display animation from dynamic list of images. I want to use AnimationDrawable for this purpose, but unfortunately I am stuck... :( my code is as

```
ImageView globe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.globe);

AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
animation.setOneShot(true);

Resources res = this.getResources();

while (from <= to) {
    String name = "globe_" + String.format("%03d", from);
    int globeId = res.getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
            this.getPackageName());
    animation.addFrame(res.getDrawable(globeId), 200);
    from++;
}

globe.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
globe.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            animation.start();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just did `animation.start()` after the loop and called the function from a runnable and it worked

```
while (from <= to) {
    String name = "globe_" + String.format("%03d", from);
    int globeId = res.getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
            this.getPackageName());

    animation.addFrame(res.getDrawable(globeId), 200);
    from++;
}

globe.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

animation.start()
```

Answer (score 7):

So Animation.addFrame(Drawable frame, int duration) takes a drawable which you can create from a Bitmap.

If your list of images are dynamically loaded:

```
List<Bitmap> images;
int duration = 200;    

for(Bitmap image: images){
    BitmapDrawable frame = new BitmapDrawable(image);
    animation.addFrame(frame, duration);
}
```

Try this out, should definitely work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I am already adding the drawable through animation.addFrame(res.getDrawable(globeId), 200); and I tried your way as well, but no luck :(

Comment: Sorry about that, take a look at this linke and tell me how it goes: http://androidforums.com/application-development/11620-programmatic-frame-frame-animation-examle-animationdrawable.html