# Android: Animation List Changing Dynamically

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an animation.xml with 4 frames.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/male01a" android:duration="4000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/male01b" android:duration="1100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/male01c" android:duration="1100" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/male01d" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

Is there anyway I can use some sort of variable here for each drawable? Much like using  "@string/animation1" where animation1 points to "@drawable/male01a" in Strings.xml. But I need some way to change the drawables, say to male02a, in the code.

Comment: See this stackoverflow question, a good solution to this problem: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149487/animationdrawable-programmatically-without-animation-list-xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149487/animationdrawable-programmatically-without-animation-list-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add frames to your animation using the method addFrame().

Example:

```
ImageView imview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable) imview.getDrawable();
Drawable frame = Drawable.createFromPath("your image path");
ad.addFrame(frame, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your goal :

You can change the drawable (image) of a specific item into the listView programatically.
You will need to make your own xml file to describe the items.

Example "list_item.xml" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I suggest you to try this library if you want to make an animation for the entire listView :
[ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations)