# Which is the best strategy to show an animated view that haves multiple frames?

Tags: android, animation, view

I want to show a view on the screen that is a mouth opening and closing itself.

The mouth will have 3 frames (3 image states), opened, closed, and semi-opened.

I want each frame to be wait 300ms until the next frame is showed.

Which is the best strategy to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html):

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="300" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="300" />
</animation-list>
```

and then:

```
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list_resource_name);
    AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
    animation.start();
```

Comment: nice, it is possible to create the animation list with java code?

Comment: I suppose it is, although I can't think of a reason to do it, refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149487/animationdrawable-programmatically-without-animation-list-xml

Comment: thanks :) and... it is possible to changue the animation with another one with other frames when i want? for example, when the user has touched the image or something

Comment: Sure, use a selector for that. see this link: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/